# CSS3 animation speed after hover not right in Webkit browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit, background-position

Its difficult to explain the problem I'm trying to solve. I've made a very simple JSFiddle to help.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Njmz/1/

```
#image {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-image:url('http://th07.deviantart.net/images3/PRE/i/2004/142/8/b/Tileable_Checkered_Floor.jpg');
    background-size:150%;
    background-position:left center;
    transition:5s linear;
    -moz-transition:5s linear;
    -webkit-transition:5s linear;

}

#image:hover {
    background-position:right center;
}
```

Basically everything works as I'd like it to in Firefox, when you hover over the background scrolls across, and if you take your mouse away if reverts back at the *same* speed, even if the animation hadn't finished. However in Safari/Chrome it animates back over the same time, so much slower if the animation hadn't finished, if you don't understand you'll see what I mean when you see it. Basically is there a simple fix for this through CSS or am I going to need to write some Javascript to fix this?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Should not need any js for this fix.

Comment: hopefully not! I'd be tempted to put up with it as it is, I imagine the js could get quite involved

Answer (score 0):

Just add the transition time to your :hover class.

```
#image:hover {
    background-position:right center;
    -moz-transition:2s linear;
    -webkit-transition:2s linear;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Njmz/2/

Comment: that didn't seem to solve it for me, I think the time would need to be adjusted depending on how long the user was hovered for. But Firefox seems to do this calculation for you.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, you want it to revert at the same speed it moved at?

Comment: What version of chrome are you using, i tested this across chrome, safari, ie, all work fine.

Comment: The latest Chrome and Safari on mac, yeah I'd like it revert at the same speed, even if the mouse has been moved off before the animation completes. If you let it get to the end its fine, if you move it off straight away it animates back that small amount over 5 seconds which looks ridiculous. Firefox is the only browser I've tested that doesn't have this issue.